# How could the Death Eaters Apparate straight to Voldemort without knowing where he is?

Tags: harry-potter, voldemort, death-eaters, apparition

In this question, I am speaking mostly about the first time Voldemort calls them after being reconstituted at the end of *Goblet of Fire*. Here, there is no indication that they had been informed that Voldemort would be at the graveyard in advance (indeed, no one knew that he was back in Britain save for Peter Pettigrew and Barty Crouch Jr).

We know that Death Eaters can be contacted by Voldemort through the Dark Mark tattoo on their arms. Once they feel the 'call', they are to Disapparate and Apparate immediately to him. But since they need to know the 'destination' (one of the "Three D's" of Apparition), how are they able reach him without knowing the location of where he was?

Is there an explanation for this related to the Dark Mark 'tattoo contact spell' (my ineloquent term for it)? Is there some other power alluded to elsewhere in the series?

I think the question matters, because if they were able to find and reach Voldemort through Apparition, without precise knowledge of the location/destination (i.e. exactly where Voldemort is), why couldn't the Death Eaters do the same when trying to find Harry (or anyone), especially in *Deathly Hallows*, when Harry was over 17 and away from Hogwarts and other forms of protection? And conversely, why couldn't the Ministry, Aurors, members of the Order of the Phoenix or anyone Apparate to find Voldemort and capture him?

Comment: It sounds like this question is really asking, "Does the dark mark allow Voldemort to reveal his location?" Which I can only assume the answer is yes, and that it's a beacon signaling his followers to rally to him.

Comment: Because of magic.

Comment: How can Death Eaters teleport to someone that broke the Taboo without really knowing their location.  How can people detect 'underage' wizard magic, but exclude children living in the homes of adult wizards, and send owls nearly immediately accompanied by a popping sound..  Those are two other examples of the location of magic use is detected, and has resulted in apparation.

Answer (score 4):

It isn't specified outright in the books, but either the tattoo tells them where Voldemort is or when they apparate after receiving the call the tattoo directs them to Voldemort like the deluminator directed Ron to Harry and Hermoine.